# How to load angular controllers and HTML Templates without route Providers for non-spa | Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Am creating an application which is a non-Single Page Application.

I am using require js and angular AMD to implement my application. As it is a non-SPA, am not finding a way to load the templates and controllers.

Expected Output:

1. How to load the Controllers on my page without using route provider.
2. How to load html templates using text plugin.

This is my project structure:

[image]

CODE:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link href="./css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <link href="./css/swiper.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

    <style>

    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div ng-view id="main-container" class="container-fluid"></div>

    <script data-main="js/main.js" src="js/lib/require/require.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
define( [ "angularAMD", "aRoute", "swiper", "angularSwiper", "Services/services", "Directives/directives", "Filters/filters" ],

    function (angularAMD, angularRoute, Swiper, AngularSwiper, Services, Directives, Filters){

        var app = angular.module('testApp', ['ksSwiper']);

        app.config(function($locationProvider) {

            $locationProvider.html5Mode({
              enabled: true,
              requireBase: false
            });

        });

        Filters.initialize(app);

        app.factory(Services);
        app.directive(Directives);

        // Bootstrap Angular when DOM is ready
        return angularAMD.bootstrap(app);
});
```

Main.js:

```
// Require JS  Config File

require.config({

    baseUrl: 'js/',

    // alias libraries paths
    paths : {
        "angular" : "lib/angular/angular",
        'angularAMD': 'lib/angular/angularAMD',
        "aRoute": "lib/angular/angular-route",
        'ngload': 'lib/angular/ngload',
        "angularSwiper": "lib/angular/angular-swiper",
        "swiper": "lib/swiper/swiper",
        "text": "lib/require/text",

        'testCtrl': 'js/Controllers/controllers'
    },

    // Add angular modules that does not support AMD out of the box, put it in a shim
    shim : {
        angular  :{
            exports : "angular"
        },
        angularAMD  :{
            deps: ['angular'],
            exports : "angularAMD"
        },
        aRoute  :{
            deps: ['angular'],
            exports : "aRoute"
        },
        swiper:{
            deps:['angular'],
            exports: "swiper"
        },
        angularSwiper:{
            deps: ['swiper'],
            exports: "angularSwiper"
        }

    },


    // kick start application
    deps: ['app']
});
```

controller.js:

```
define(['app', 'text!templates/Main.html'], function (app, template) {
    app.controller('testCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {
        console.log("controller loaded");
        $scope.title = "angularAMD";
    });
});
```

main.html:

```
<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: at least You need grunt, gulp to make some app to render layout html with injected template. otherwise You'll have to make different html files like index.html with same but different content part. for example some php devs when starting develop angular app they output some template from serverside that has same structure but different content element that calls controller

Comment: not sure what the benefit of using require.js and angular is. you can just define your controllers as...angular controllers, put them in your `index.html` and angular does the hard work of loading asynchronously.  the "real" controller then becomes your backend which determines which frontend angular controllers to load in script tags